# Javascript Shorthand

Tags: javascript

Is there a shorthand version of the following:

```
(a > 0 && a < 1000 && b > 0 && b < 1000 && c > 0 && c < 1000)
```

Many thanks.

Comment: All of the solutions here will be slower than just making that large if statement.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, there isn't really any shorthand. There is no simple inline way to specify a comparison like that so that it could be repeated for different variables.

You could make a function for validating values:

```
function between(min, max, values) {
  for (var i = 2; i < arguments.length; i++) {
    if (arguments[i] < min || arguments[i] > max) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

and call it using:

```
between(1, 999, a, b, c)
```

Comment: @Guffa: Is there a missing comma? `min max`

Comment: +1, could also make an higher-order function factory out of this. And add a comma.

Comment: @Guffa: Is the 'values' parameter needed in the function definition ?

Comment: @Mahesh - nope, you can leave it off

Comment: @Mahesh Velaga: It's just there to hint that there are more parameters expected, you can leave it out, or write it as a comment: `function between(min, max /*,values... */) {`.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of ways to do this. Personally if I was doing this a *lot*, I'd define a function once:

```
function between(val, min, max) { return min < val && val < max; }
```

Then your `if` checks look like:

```
if(between(a, 0, 1000) && between(b, 0, 1000) && between(c, 0, 1000))
```

---

The alternative is to add a method onto the numbers themselves:

```
Number.prototype.between = function(min,max) { return min<this && this<max; };
```

Then use it like this:

```
if(a.between(0, 1000) && b.between(0, 1000) && c.between(0, 1000))
```

Though this it's much cleaner...or you may want to go another route altogether.

---

**Note:** both of these approaches are for *you*. They will run slower, they're just a bit easier to maintain...the closure compiler would inline most of it with advanced optimizations though.

Comment: If you stop using commas where full stops belong, I promise I'll buy your jQuery book ;)

Comment: @BGerrissen - If you're range check is always 0 and 1000, it becomes much shower...the above was a general example :)

Comment: @sje397 - I have a book?, are you sure?, news to me. :)

Comment: @Nick Craver: You should have - I think you pretty much taught me jQuery. I should have added 'when it comes out'.

Comment: @sje397 - I was just taunting the inner-comma demons in you, updated :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Number.prototype.isInRange = function(low, high) {
   return this > low && this < high;
}
```

Now try this:

```
(a.isInRange(0,1000) && b.isInRange(0,1000) && c.isInRange(0,1000))
```

If you want, you can rename the function to your liking to save some more keystrokes. I will go with readability though :)

Comment: That's actually longer, just less repetitive. :o)

Comment: This won't work, you've just defined a function, not on anything...it needs to be on the prototype of what you're calling.

Answer (score 1):

If there's no chance that `a,b,c` will be a negative number, you could do this:

```
(a && b && c && a < 1000 && b < 1000 && c < 1000)
```

Or if you wanted to just clean it up a bit, you could add line breaks if you're not opposed to the practice.

```
(a > 0 && a < 1000 && 
 b > 0 && b < 1000 && 
 c > 0 && c < 1000)
```

No shorter, but much easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

If you're worried about the number of comparisons, no there is no shortcut.  If you want to reduce the number of characters in the comparison, you could write a "between zero and 2000" function and call it three times.

Answer (score -1):

you could use one & :

```
(a > 0 & a < 1000 & b > 0 & b < 1000 & c > 0 & c < 1000)
```

nothing else comes to my mind

Comment: ... which is a horrible idea and doesn't help much anyway.

Comment: & is not the same as && - although it will work the same in most cases it is bitwise AND whereas && is boolean AND.  Even where it works the same the bitwise operator will have more overhead as it requires switching between boolean and binary comparisons

Comment: -1 never do this unless you're actually doing bitwise operations.